# Select rows where data has a pattern in columns

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

A rather specific question. I have a dataset of unique ID numbers and then 15 dummy columns flagging whether the ID has appeared in a corresponding dataset.

There 260k unique ID numbers dummy columns stand for months. I would like to subset only those ID numbers where there is a 'break', there is a 0 in a column, inbetween two 1's.

Not sure how to go about doing it,any help would be welcome. Below is a glimpse at  my data

```
      id      m2210 m2211 m2212 m2301 m2302 m2303 etc
1   07W74814    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
2   07W77348    0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
3   07W79970    1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4   07W83630    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   07W85211    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
6   07W90765    0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   07W98267    0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
8   08W03543    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
9   08W14545    0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
10  08W17338    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  08W20909    0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
12  08W22726    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  08W31747    0   1   1   1   1   1   0
```

So I would like to create a column that flags if particular ID has a 'break' pattern in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this should work. We reshape long, filter for the 1 / 0 / 1 pattern, keep one row per id, and join that to the original to just keep those id's.

```
df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  filter(lag(value) == 1 & value == 0 & lead(value) == 1), .by = id) |> 
  distinct(id) |>
  left_join(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  unite(sequence, -id, remove = FALSE, sep = "") |> # create a string where all the 0s and 1s are combined 
  filter(
    str_detect(sequence, "101") # remove rows without the "101"
  )  |>
  select(-sequence) # remove sequence variable now that it's not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

If a **base R** approach is ok, using `apply` and `grepl` with `paste`

```
cbind(df, flag = apply(df[,-1], 1, \(x) grepl("101", paste(x, collapse=""))))
```

output

```
         id m2210 m2211 m2212 m2301 m2302 m2303 m2214 m2215 m2216 m2307 m2308
1  07W74814     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2  07W77348     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
3  07W79970     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
4  07W83630     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
5  07W85211     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
6  07W90765     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
7  07W98267     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
8  08W03543     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
9  08W14545     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
10 08W17338     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
11 08W20909     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
12 08W22726     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
13 08W31747     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
   m2309 m2250 m2261 m2272  flag
1      1     1     1     0 FALSE
2      0     1     0     0  TRUE
3      1     1     1     1  TRUE
4      0     0     0     0  TRUE
5      1     1     1     1 FALSE
6      0     0     0     0 FALSE
7      1     1     1     1 FALSE
8      1     0     0     0 FALSE
9      1     1     1     1 FALSE
10     0     0     0     0 FALSE
11     1     1     1     1 FALSE
12     0     0     0     0 FALSE
13     1     1     0     0 FALSE
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("07W74814", "07W77348", "07W79970", "07W83630", 
"07W85211", "07W90765", "07W98267", "08W03543", "08W14545", "08W17338", 
"08W20909", "08W22726", "08W31747"), m2210 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), m2211 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), m2212 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), m2301 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2302 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2303 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2214 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), m2215 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), m2216 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2307 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2308 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2309 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2250 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), m2261 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), m2272 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare *all* column values at once, i.e.: to have 101 pattern, 0 must be on 3rd column, and must have 1 on 2nd and 4th columns, etc.

```
rowSums(df[, c(3:(ncol(df) - 1))] == 0 &
          df[, c(2:(ncol(df) - 2))] == 1 &
          df[, c(4:ncol(df))] == 1) > 0
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This should outperform looping, data reshaping, and regex solutions.